# C4965 in WinRT: implicit boxing of integer 0

Tags: visual-studio-2012, c++-cx

In VS 2012, I'm getting error C4965 (Implizites Boxing mit ganzer Zahl 0. Verwenden Sie "nullptr" oder eine explizite Umwandlung), when passing `0` where `Platform::Object^` is expected. The intention of the code is indeed to pass the integer value 0, not a null reference. Apparently, in C++/CLI etc., there is a __box keyword that can be used, but this is not recognized by the C++/CX compiler.

So: what's the proper way to suppress this warning, and to create a boxed WinRT integer?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to MSDN, you should use explicit boxing. It suggests

```
safe_cast<System::Object^>(0)
```

... so you're making clear it is not nullptr. 
In your case, this would probably be:

```
safe_cast<Platform::Object^>(0)
```